# Finding the quiet section of the synagogue

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, how-to, kavana-concentration, loud-quiet

When you enter an unfamiliar synagogue, how do you find a seat in a section that's likely to have the least talking?

Comment: This question inspired by this blog post by The Rebbetzin's Husband: http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-cook-corn-on-cob.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest sitting towards the front, or somewhere near the amud. Most of the talking usually takes place towards the rear of the synagogue.

Comment: Hello yydl - welcome to mi.yodeya and thank you for your experience-based concise answer!

Answer (score 9):

Women' section advice: If the mechitza is down the middle, sit up front. If the women are in back or in a balcony, sit in the back row.

Comment: Auntie, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing the female perspective! Please consider clicking on "register," above to create your account. This will allow you to take full credit for your contributions.

Answer (score 9):

In the Men's side as close to the Rabbi as possible.