# How to respond to excessive talking in a synagogue

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tzibur-community, speech-talking, ahavat-yisrael

If there is a lot of talking (or other halakhic impropriety) in a synagogue, what are some of the considerations that go into the decision regarding what to do about it?

Here are some ideas of what to do, though there may be more:

1. do nothing and continue praying at my synagogue and attempt to set a good example (but risk being distracted in my prayers and c"v be seduced by the negative environment around me into committing the exact same crimes that I am worried about);
2. pray by myself at home (but without a minyan, so I miss out on Barchu, Kedushah, Torah reading, Kaddish, et al.);
3. be a whistleblower and try to establish a breakaway minyan (but risk being cold-shouldered by the "establishment" or annihilated by an angry mob).

(somehow inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1422/1059))

Comment: sources: http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2010/01/breakaway-minyanim-sources.html, http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/mb/83mb.htm see also r.m.moshe's very machmir teshuva about breakaway minyanim.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/how-can-we-get-people-to-stop-talking-much-loudly-during-minyan

Comment: Perhaps in a nice way you can inspire them to stop talking during Tefila.

Comment: @arielK where is this Teshuva?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Choshen Mishpat I §38

Comment: @ArielK - Could you please sum up the maskana of the teshuva?

Comment: Going to another Shul where there isn't as much talking isn't an option?

Comment: @AdamMosheh If it's the teshuvah I'm thinking of, R' Moshe says one may break away either out of physical necessity (there's no more standing room in the current minyan), or out of spiritual necessity (want a different hashkafah - I think R' Moshe holds its specifically when you want to be more machmir on halachos the shul is more meikel about, that is, moving "toward the right"). My words, not his.

Comment: @AEML Unfortunately such an option isn't always so pashut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we are am yisrael and we must tolerate each other, we must do everything we can to try and be united, so the best solution is sit next to people that dont talk

Comment: +1, "we are am yisrael and we must tolerate each other, we must do everything we can to try and be united" ... BEST ANSWER!!!

Answer (score 4):

I choose option 1 (be a good example) because I think that option 2 (pray at home) is hurting you more than helping you and option 3 (break away minyan) goes against the duty of all who are able to combine Yiras Shamayim and Ahavas Yisrael.

Personally, I only react to talking if it is particularly loud and/or actually disturbing me during the Amidah. I do my best to ignore the sadly common [susurrus](http://www.google.co.za/search?q=susurrus) in shul, accepting that most people present in my shul are simply waiting for the service to end, being unable to understand the Hebrew they are reading.

In the spirit of "it takes a village to raise a child", though, if there are young kids with whom I have a friendly relationship who are talking loudly I will shush them audibly, trying to show exasperation rather than anger.

If there are adults making a lot of noise while I'm davening I try to to show them that they're disturbing me by quietly and without fuss closing my eyes and... ahem... **sticking my fingers in my ears**. Yes, it makes me look stupid, but I feel it gets my point across accurately and without embarrassing any (other) individual. This is an *indirect* rebuke and has never evoked an angry response. It doesn't *work* very well (the conversation  usually continues), but it's my way of protesting.

Let me also say that I do not to any degree expect the talking behaviour of the shul to change through my example. I feel obliged to protest, but it would be tragically arrogant to think I have that much influence. My part is to behave properly myself.

Comment: "sticking my fingers in my ears" - you're silly, +1.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Thank you. ;-) I am not making it up. I really do this when the talking gets too much. It shows my feelings and shuts out the noise at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Call out for the people to be quiet!

Comment: If you read my question thoroughly, I am also worried about generating hatred between Jews, so I'm not so sure this would be the best idea.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Your enumerated options do seem to leave out trying to overtly influence the congregation you're in, which needn't necessarily be done in a manner that generates hatred (or certainly no more necessarily than breaking away would).

Comment: Welcome to the site Jack, I hope to see you around!

Comment: JackTheWack, I second HachamGabriel's welcome, and am writing merely to add (a) that answers with detail and sources and/or reasoning generally are much more helpful than those that merely make an assertion or provide an idea and that (b) that you should [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1684/jack-the-wack) in order to [gain access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.